# How do I get root dir of python wsgi app within an imported module?

Tags: python

Nginx with WSGI is loading a file in my root directory called `run.py`

Within `run.py` I get the root directory with

`ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))`

This works fine.

I now want to access this root variable within an imported module.
I hear that globals are evil. But it seems odd to pass the root path into the modules that I'd like to use. What is the most pythonic way to work with this?

Also - the reason why I want the root path is because I'm doing this within an imported module.

`os.chdir('/some/path')`

and I'd like to change back to the root path later in the script.

`os.chdir(ROOT)`

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that, although it seems odd to you, explicitly passing the path to the modules is actually the best solution if you need it inside your modules.

Further, you should ensure your modules *always use absolute paths* (that is, you shouldn't need `chdir` at all).

The reason for this is that the current working directory is a *global state* (it's scope is the process'). As you mention, global state is "evil" - it can be modified by any one of your modules freely, which can lead to subtle errors - especially when dealing with concurrency ([as in a threaded WSGI webserver](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading)).

If you really want to `chdir`, you can [use a context manager](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576620-changedirectory-context-manager/) to avoid forgetting to change it back, *but this doesn't solve the concurrent access problem*.

Comment: Yes, I've been having issues with the global nature of chdir. Is was messing up my scripts. Thanks for the learning - really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How about remember the current working directory, then restore later:

```
ROOT = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/some/path')
...
os.chdir(ROOT)
```

Comment: It worked. I read somewhere that os.getcwd() was not reliable in all cases. Do you know why? (Or perhaps I misread about it)

Comment: @Boz, If your program is multi-thread and each thread changes working directory, `os.getcwd()` work unreliably. If the program is single-threaded and there's no additional `chdir()` call, it's okay.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm going to avoid using it altogether.